# How can I streamline/improve/beautify my auto-form JS code?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've got a Javascript (dojo) function that I'm using to auto-populate a form. The idea is to pass in a JS object with keys for the form field ids, and values that help define how to fill in the field.

It works, but it feels a bit ugly to me (the switch statement, the objects within objects syntax). Any thoughts on how can I improve* this code?

```
/**
 * Fill in the form with passed in values
 *
 * @param {Object} defaults 
 *
 * Can be used to pass in default values to the form. Expects an object like this:
 *      {<field id>: {type: '<field type>', value:'<value>'}
 *
 *      for example:
 *      {
 *      paymethod: {type: 'select', value:'Account Transfer'},   // html select
 *      fundsource: {type: 'combo', value:'Corporation Account'} // dijit.comboBox
 *      }
 */
function fillDefaults(defaults) {
    var props;
    for (var field in defaults) {
        props = defaults[field];
        switch (props['type']) {
            // so far only select and combo have been implemented 
            // others will be added as needed
            // and maybe grouped depending on how they work 
            // (e.g. all dijits together, <input> with <select>, etc.)
            case 'select':
                dojo.byId(field).value = props['value'];
                dojo.byId(field).onchange()
                break;
            case 'combo':
                dijit.byId(field).attr('value', props['value']);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[*] improve: make prettier, more js-like, more dojo-like, more streamlined

Answer (score 1):

What does pretty mean? What's js-like?

A switch, although memory intensive, is cleaner if you plan to extend with more objects.

Maybe, instead of a switch, have an object containing your functions:

```
funcs = {
  select: function(value) {
    dojo.byId(field).value = value;
    dojo.byId(field).onchange()
  },
  combo: function(value) {
    dijit.byId(field).attr('value', value);
  }
};

function payFillDefaults(defaults) {
  var props;
  for(var field in defaults) {
    props = defaults[field];
    if(funcs[props['type']]) {
      funcs[props['type']](props['value']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A switch is memory intensive? Can you justify that statement?

Comment: We ran some tests last year on an A.I. interpreter written in JS. The parser had massive condition chains which were all written with switches to aid readability. After testing if/else vs switch we found if/else to evaluate faster than the switches. However, what with TraceMonkey and Google's V8 my statement may bare less weight now. No justification, just experience. I'm pretty sure I watched a vid a while back of Douglas Crockford talking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Improved a bit according [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) standards:

```
function fillDefaults(defaults) {
    var props, field;
    for (field in defaults) {
        props = defaults[field];
        switch (props.type) {
        case 'select':
            dojo.byId(field).value = props.value;
            dojo.byId(field).onchange();
            break;
        case 'combo':
            dijit.byId(field).attr('value', props.value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`dojox.form.manager`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/form/manager/index?action=show&redirect=dojox%2Fform%2Fmanager) — it does approximately what you want to achieve. It support existing form widgets (["main" mixin](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/form/manager/_Mixin)), practically all DOM form elements ([node mixin](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/form/manager/_NodeMixin)), the unified event processing, and so on. It can be used with unmodified forms.

As you would probably guessed already it is structured as a set of independent mix-ins so you can select only required functionality. For convenience and as an example there a class, which combines all mix-ins together: [`Manager`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/form/Manager).

Read what it does, see if it fits your needs, if not, study its code and borrow what you like. If it misses something — share your feedback on [the mailing list](http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/mailman/listinfo/dojo-interest) ([on gmane.org](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.dojo.user)). Or, if you can improve it, contribute back.